# how to make this asp.net code redirect to a different page after submit

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

First and foremost I do not have access to the controller part, the website it's already compiled and I do not have the source just the .dll

```
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Details", "Shop", FormMethod.Post, new { role = "form"}))
        {
<p>Select Character：</p>
            if (Model.Chars != null && Model.Chars.Count > 0)
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                @Html.ValidationSummary("", new {@class = "text-danger"})
                if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
                {

                    @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.Guid, Model.Guid)

                    for (var index = 0; index < Model.Chars.Count; index++)
                    {
                        var charInfo = Model.Chars[index];
                        var chdata = charInfo.Name + " (lv." + charInfo.Level + ")";

                        if (index == 0)
                        {
                            <div>
                                @Html.RadioButtonFor((x) => Model.CharName, charInfo.Name, new {Checked = "checked"}) @chdata
                            </div>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <div>
                                @Html.RadioButtonFor((x) => Model.CharName, charInfo.Name) @chdata
                            </div>
                        }
                    }
                }
<p/>
                <input type="submit" class="position: center !important" value="Confirm Purchase"/>
            }
            else if (Model.Chars == null)
            {
                <h4 class="nk-title h4" style="color: red">To purchase items, you must first log in to your account</h4>
            }
            else
            {
                <h4 class="nk-title h4" style="color: red">You cannot buy items, you don't have any characters in your account</h4>
            }
        }
```

normally it should redirect to Shop when it receives the notification BuyOk as stated in **_Layout.cshtml** but it doesn't.

```
    @{
        var messages = ViewBag.Errors as List<ViewError>;
        var notifications = ViewBag.Notifications as List<ViewNotification>;
    }

    @if (notifications != null && notifications.Count > 0)
    {
        <div class="alert" style="background: #00ff00">
            @foreach (var message in notifications)
            {
                <span class="closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display = 'none';">&times;</span>

                string msg;

                switch (message)
                {
                    case ViewNotification.BuyOk:
                        msg = "Purchase complete";
                        break;
                    case ViewNotification.ChangePwdOk:
                        msg = "Password change request successful, description sent to your email";
                        break;
                    case ViewNotification.ChangePwdSuccess:
                        msg = "Password Changed";
                        break;
                    case ViewNotification.ChangeEmailSuccess:
                        msg = "Email has been changed";
                        break;
                    default:
                        msg = "Unknown notification";
                        break;
                }

                @msg
            }
        </div>
    }
```

There are no errors but **case ViewNotification.BuyOk:** it's not triggered therefore after pressing the submit button the action is completed without any errors but it doesn't redirect to Shop

What I wanna do is to redirect to Shop after I press Confirm Purchase

PS: I only own the compiled code, I tried to decompile with several decompiling software but so far no luck and I cannot see the real controller nor can I edit it

I hope someone can help me with this issue, Thank you

Comment: how in the world can you make any changes without changing code in the controller? Time to make a new controller and start migrating pages.

Comment: on completion, the website is redirected and isOk=False or isOk=True was added at the end of the URL. I used javascript to create a redirection if isOk=True exists in the URL. Sadly I don't have the time to recreate everything at this moment. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on completion, the website is redirected and isOk=False or isOk=True was added at the end of the URL. I used javascript to create a redirection if isOk=True exists in the URL. Thank you